# display HTML5 in swing

Tags: java, html, swing, javafx-2

I have seen many questions here about displaying HTML content in a swing application. But none of the libraries support html5(I cant afford JxBrowser).

I have some locally stored html5 webpages and i want to show them in my swing application. One idea is embedding firefox or chrome into my java application and removing the controls.

How can I display html5 content in my swing application?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should look into new JavaFX browser that fully supports HTML5 and written in pure Java. You can easily integrate it into any Swing application - see the official description:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm

But i guess it might force you to use JDK7+ to fully support various OS.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to necro this old thread.  But, this is still a very relevant question today, so I'd thought I'd chime in with extra information and options.

Agree with the comments above about **WebKit**.  It's built into Java, it's fast, and it's free, and it is so easy to use.  Oracle's tutorials / examples on this are some of the best and clearest I've seen on their web site (you will be up and running with a basic Java web page display app very quickly):
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm

There is really only 1 restriction / limitation with WebKit:  it is JavaFX, you cannot embed it directly into Swing or AWT controls.  However, you can embed the JavaFX scene in a Swing JPanel (or other container) so your Swing App can show the HTML5.

And, with Oracle now "decoupling JavaFX" (and therefore WebKit) from the main JDK / JRE, this might add extra steps to people wanting to use your Java App.  e.g. they might need to download and install JavaFX for their platform separately (it it exists).

Ref: **Java SE 11: The Great Removal**, 
https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/9nakq3/java_se_11_the_great_removal/

Or you could use something like GraalVM (or some other packager) to build a stand alone application and distribute that.

Ref: **Ten Things You Can Do With GraalVM - Oleg Šelajev**, 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tEaEAq0L9Pk

**Anyway, hope this helps someone.  :)**

Answer (score 1):

**WebKit is integrated in Java 8**, so you don't need to jump through hoops. It is continuously update. It is available as the [JavaFX WebView control](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm). Java also comes with the Nashorn javascript engine that can call Java from JavaScript. Overall performance [is excellent](https://justmy2bits.com/2013/09/08/javafx-with-nashorn-canvas-example/).